# Start a program from the WindowsApps folder for a standard user from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, file-permissions, file-access, group-policy

In Group Policy Editor at the GPO `Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Logon>Run these programs at user logon` I have set a program to run which is located at `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Foo\Bar.exe"`. When the user Admin (who has access to the folder `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"`) logs on the program starts just fine, but when NotAdmin (who doesn't have access) logs on, the program never starts.

I've tried running it as system, opening it from cmd, etc., but nothing works. I'm particularly confused because I know that a standard user can start a program installed from the Microsoft Store just fine if they use the shortcut provided by the store, even if they don't have access to the folder. Is there any way to fix this (considering the fact that it has to be in the `WindowsApps` folder and that the user is not allowed to have any access settings changed from the factory defaults)?